# Display image from MongoDB using reactivemongo in Play2 Scala

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I'm passing this List to a Play2 template:

```
files: Option[List[(String, reactivemongo.api.gridfs.ReadFile[reactivemongo.bson.BSONValue])]])
```

how to do I pull the first image from the List and render that image to the html tag

```
<img src=" ">
```

Any help will be GREAT :)

Thanks
Danny

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From looking at the reactive mongo demo app, it seems you have to add a route for serving the image from gridfs. Look at the [route file](https://github.com/sgodbillon/reactivemongo-demo-app/blob/master/conf/routes#L13) and the [controller](https://github.com/sgodbillon/reactivemongo-demo-app/blob/master/app/controllers/Application.scala#L158), that example shows how to serve attachments. So your case might look like that:

In the route file:

```
GET     /img/:id            controllers.Images.getImg(id)
```

And in the `Images` controller:

```
def getImg(id: String) = Action {
  Async {
    import reactivemongo.api.gridfs.Implicits.DefaultReadFileReader
    val file = gridFS.find(BSONDocument("_id" -> new BSONObjectID(id)))
    serve(gridFS, file)
  }
}
```

Then in your template:

```
@if(files.isDefined) {
    @files.get.map { file =>
    <img src="@routes.Images.getImg(file._1)"/>
  }
}
```